# Abstract Constructor on Abstract Class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, abstract-class

How can I create an abstract constructor for an abstract class?

For example, if I have this abstract class:

```
export abstract class Foo<T> extends Bar<T> {
  constructor(someParam: any) {
    super();
    this.someObj = someParam;
  }
}
```

Then it is consumed by this class:

```
export class FooImpl extends Foo<SomeType> {
}
```

If I don't override the constructor then the default parameterless constructor will be used on the `FooImpl` class which will lead to an improper state within the class.

How can I define an abstract constructor or force consumers of the abstract class to override the constructor when `Foo<T>` is consumed?

EDIT

The exact code I have is below and would appear that this is somehow related to vscode

```
export abstract class FireStoreDataSource<T> extends DataSource<T> {
  constructor(store: () => Observable<T[]>) {
    super();
  }
}
```

Then I am extending this class as follows

```
export class AssessmentCenterDataSource extends FireStoreDataSource<AssessmentCenter> {
}
```

Then creating an instance in an angular component `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = new AssessmentCenterDataSource(() => this.service.getData());
}
```

Here in vscode I am getting the compiler error `[ts] Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`, however when I run `ng build` it does build correctly

If I do not pass anything to the constructor then the compiler error goes away and I get an error when I run `ng build` which is `error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`

So it looks like this might be an issue with vscode or one of the addons I have installed rather than typescript

I am using vscode insiders 1.26.0 and typescript insiders 3.0.1 along with Angular 6

Comment: *"...then the default parameterless constructor will be used on the FooImpl class which will lead to an improper state within the class."* Leaving aside that the default won't be parameterless, improper in what way? The code in the super constructor **must** be executed, it's a requirement of `class` syntax. If you added a constructor to the subclass and didn't call `super`, it would be an error.

Answer (score 4):

Actually in Typescript if you don't override the constructor, the constructor is inherited form the base class.

So in your case this would be invalid:

```
new FooImpl(); // error
```

You would be forced to pass the parameters required by the base class:

```
new FooImpl("") //ok
```

There is no way to force the derived type to override the constructor, but since the base constructor is inherited it seems to be good enough.

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Bar%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20abstract%20class%20Foo%3CT%3E%20extends%20Bar%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someObj%3A%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(someParam%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.someObj%20%3D%20someParam%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20SomeType%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20FooImpl%20extends%20Foo%3CSomeType%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20FooImpl()%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0Anew%20FooImpl(%22%22))

Comment: This is not the case in my example I do not get any compiler error

Comment: @NeilStevens then something else might be at work, this is how it's supposed to behave. Added a playground link with your exact code and we get an error. Maybe your real code differs in some way ? Are the parameters optional ?

Comment: To elaborate, in the above (in vscode) I get a compiler error for the second one if I pass an argument

Comment: @NeilStevens this seems strange. are you sure the class you are instantiating the correct class ? Are your imports ok ?  What compiler settings are you using (although I can't really think of one that would impact this behavior)

Comment: @NeilStevens I am 100% sure of the answer provided. At least in recent versions of typescript this is the behavior (I suspect it has always been but would need to check)

Comment: Please see updated question which include the real code (although somewhat cut back to remove irrelevant code) but you will see that I am doing exactly as you state above so I will raise this with the vscode team

Comment: @NeilStevens I'm no longer at my desk but I'll try with the dev version when I can. Have you tried with 2.9? It might be an editor issue..

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `new` instance of `FooImpl` generates an error (when passing no args to the constructor, because the constructor is inherited) thereby forcing the usage of the constructor with args:

```
const f = new FooImpl();
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

Comment: Something is not quite right then, this is default behavior.

Comment: I have just copied your code and can say that I get an error if no function is passed to `new AssessmentCenterDataSource(....)`

Comment: Strange, after restarting the IDE all is correct, must make a mental note to restart the IDE before jumping on SO and looking like a fool

Comment: when nothing makes sense anymore, computer rebooting is in order :)