# Is it possible to enforce constructor parameter types with `extends` or `implements` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, constructor, abstract

I've looked at all the following:

1. [Abstract constructor type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886082/abstract-constructor-type-in-typescript)
2. [How does `type Constructor<T> = Function & { prototype: T }` apply to Abstract constructor types in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349758/how-does-type-constructort-function-prototype-t-apply-to-abstract-c/52350147#52350147)
3. [Abstract Constructor on Abstract Class in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399223/abstract-constructor-on-abstract-class-in-typescript)

The third is the closest to what I'm looking for, but (unfortunately) the answer was more for the specific issue and less for the question title.

This is (in a simplified sense) what I'd like to be able to do:

```
abstract class HasStringAsOnlyConstructorArg {
  abstract constructor(str: string);
}

class NamedCat extends HasStringAsOnlyConstructorArg {
  constructor(name: string) { console.log(`meow I'm ${name}`); }
}

class Shouter extends HasStringAsOnlyConstructorArg {
  constructor(phrase: string) { console.log(`${phrase}!!!!!!`); }
}

const creatableClasses: Array<typeof HasStringAsOnlyConstructorArg> = [NamedCat, Shouter];
creatableClasses.forEach(
  (class: typeof HasStringAsOnlyConstructorArg) => new class("Sprinkles")
);
```

In the example above you can see that Shouter and NamedCat both use one single string for their constructor.  They don't necessarily need to extend a class, they could implement an interface or something, but I really want to be able to hold a list of classes that require the exact same arguments to construct.

Is it possible to enforce a classes constructor parameter types with `extends` or `implements` in TypeScript?

EDIT: The "Possible Duplicate" appears to show how it is not possible to use `new()` in an interface for this purpose.  Perhaps there are still other ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does typescript interfaces with construct signatures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407036/how-does-typescript-interfaces-with-construct-signatures-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can do such enforcement on array itself, so it will allow only constructors with single string argument:

```
class NamedCat {
    constructor(name: string) { console.log(`meow I'm ${name}`); }
}

class Shouter {
    constructor(phrase: string) { console.log(`${phrase}!!!!!!`); }
}

type ConstructorWithSingleStringArg = new (args: string) => any;

const creatableClasses: Array<ConstructorWithSingleStringArg> = [NamedCat, Shouter];
creatableClasses.forEach(
    ctor => new ctor("Sprinkles")
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20NamedCat%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%20console.log(%60meow%20I'm%20%24%7Bname%7D%60)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Shouter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(phrase%3A%20string)%20%7B%20console.log(%60%24%7Bphrase%7D!!!!!!%60)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ConstructorWithSingleStringArg%20%3D%20new%20(args%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20creatableClasses%3A%20Array%3CConstructorWithSingleStringArg%3E%20%3D%20%5BNamedCat%2C%20Shouter%5D%3B%0D%0AcreatableClasses.forEach(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ctor%20%3D%3E%20new%20ctor(%22Sprinkles%22)%0D%0A)%3B)